# R: POSIXct time formatting

Tags: r, posixct

I'm trying to convert my data into OHLC, but it keeps on returning errors that I believe are related to an incorrectly formatted time column.

Below is what I am trying and i'm thinking it is the AM PM part, as I tried most options.

```
head(test$V1)
## [1] 9/7/2014 9:20:00 PM 9/7/2014 9:26:00 PM 9/7/2014 9:31:00 PM
## [4] 9/7/2014 9:35:00 PM 9/7/2014 9:41:00 PM 9/7/2014 9:45:00 PM
## 2876 Levels: 9/10/2014 1:01:00 AM 9/10/2014 1:01:00 PM ... N\\A

time1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(test$V1, sep=" "),format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %r"))

mydata <- xts(test[,c ("GE")], order.by=time1)
mydata <- to.minutes(mydata[,1],240,'minutes')
mydata <- align.time(xts(mydata),5 * 60) 

chartSeries(mydata)
## Error in periodicity(x) : can not calculate periodicity of 1 observation

head(mydata)
##      minutes.Open minutes.High minutes.Low minutes.Close
## <NA>      1.29531      1.29878       1.282       1.28463
```

Comment: Your format is wrong. It should be `time1 <- as.POSIXct(test$V1, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")`.

Comment: @user3773444 if you have found the solution to your problem, consider writing an answer yourself and accepting it to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

```
time1 <- as.POSIXct(test$V1, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```